# Android trying to figure out how to center text

Tags: android

I have the following code to display a message at the top of the screen. I cannot figure out how to center it.

Currently my code looks like:

```
int scale = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                (float) 123.4, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int size = (int) (64 * scale + 0.5f);
size=scale*10;
paint.setTextSize( 30);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
String say="Select Catagory";
canvas.drawText(say, cGlobals.TranslateX(300),cGlobals.TranslateY(100), paint);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set paint alignment:

```
paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
```

Please note that text will be centered relative to the x,y origin you specified in `Canvas.drawText()`. So you have to calculate center point of your view first

Answer (score 0):

You can align the text in the center of the textview like this:

```
paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
```

or put the textview itself in the center of the larger layout

```
paint.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: paint doesn't have `gravity` attribute. I think you meant view?

Comment: Also, OP is not using TextView at all, but drawing directly on Canvas. (Though I'm not sure why, as TextView would be a lot easier in most cases.)